# How to update the previous Screen's useState value and refresh the screen on click of goBack()

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-router

I want to update the previous screen's useState value and refresh the screen on click of goBack(), I know there is a useIsFocused() to do that but using this screen it is refreshing every time i goBack to the screen, suppose there is a ScreenA and ScreenB, So when user is performing any action in ScreeB then I am dispatching a value using redux and on goBack I am updating the useState value and refreshing the screenA, But it not working, I don't know what's the problem, Please help.

ScreenB

```
const leaveGroup = () => {
    hideMenu();
    callLikeMindsApi(`URL`, httpMethods.HTTP_PUT)
      .then(response => {
        if (response && response.data && response.data.success) {
          hideMenu();
          dispatch(updateHomeScreen(true));
          props.navigation.goBack();
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Alert.alert('FAILED', error.response.data.error_message);
      });
  };
```

And In ScreenA

```
const {updateValue} = useSelector(state => state.homeReducer);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('updateValue-1234', updateValue);
  }); // it is printing true in console if (updateValue) { setOffset(1); setTotalPages(1); setMyChatRooms([]); getUserData(); } }, [isFocused]);
```

But

```
setOffset(1);
setTotalPages(1);
setMyChatRooms([]);
```

values are not updating, if I remove the if(updateValue){} and writing like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    setOffset(1);
    setTotalPages(1);
    setMyChatRooms([]);
    getUserData();
  }, [isFocused]);
```

then code is working as expected, But it is refreshing every time I come back to the screenA and I want to refresh conditionally.

Comment: Your requirement is a valid case and this requires a trick to be done because it is not recommended to pass a function (or state) in navigate call. Why I'm not talking about goBack? Because goBack doesn't have route param and you don't want to trigger every isFocused true in ScreenA. Are you familiar with useContext? You can make a flag state in context, set it as true from ScreenB, and hook it to useEffect in ScreenA (in dependency array). Don't  forget to set it as false after it is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of props.navigation.goBack(); do

```
props.navigation.navigate('ScreenA',{details});
```

with the prop that you want pass

in screen A get that value in state from route params

```
ScreenA = (props) => {
 
   const [navigateState] = useState(props.route.params.details||{});

---while navigating to Screen B---

   props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB',{details: navigateState});
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get full your code and understand the full logic but if you have already implemented redux you should use it like this:

```
const {updateValue} = useSelector(state => state.homeReducer);
useEffect(()=>{
  if (updateValue) {
    // update your screen juse by setting some states on the current component.
  } else {
   // don't update
  }
}, [updateValue])
```

if you dispatch true value for updateValue whereever in your app then screen-A would be updated regardless it's getting focus or not. if you want to update screen-A only when it's on focus you should add focus condition in useEffect.